# How to pass a Django object from template to view by POST request?

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to pass the value of a checkbox to my views.py in the following way:

**my_template.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="playlist" value='{{ playlist }}'>
```

**views.py**

```
json_str_list = request.POST.getlist('playlist')
```

The serialized JSON in `json_str_list` looks like this:

```
'{\'id\': \'UUkfDws3roWo1GaA3pZUzfIQ\', \'title\': "Item 1", \'created_on\': datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 12, 20, 44, 41, 392273, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}'
```

This seems not to be a valid JSON string. Can I adjust the way how Django serializes the object?

I want to deserialize the JSON back to an object with json.loads() and get following error

> Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your code to pass the object's ID and deserialize it back in the view:

**my_template.html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="playlist" value="{{ playlist.id }}">
```

Try

```
import json

def my_view(request):
    playlist_id = request.POST.get('playlist')
    # Assuming you have a Playlist model with an 'id' field
    playlist = Playlist.objects.get(id=playlist_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed a working solution but I'm still interested if there is a way to pass the entire object back as a valid JSON.

Comment: You would want to add a serializer. Depending on the complexity of your `Playlist` object maybe [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/serialization/#serializing-data) (replace "xml" with "json") is already enough for you. If not you need to implement a custom json serializer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).